# VBA - surround data with double quotes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to prepare my data to be inserted in a SQL database, so certain pieces need to be surrounded by quotes.

```
For Each r In Range("A2", last_data)
    r.Value2 = """ & r.Value2 & """
Next r
```

This just populates everything with 'r.value2'. Using a single quote makes it only appear on the right side of the word.

Essentially, the sheet needs to be modified so every word is surrounded by double quotes. I had a custom code in Excel that surrounded everything with quotes but when VBA reads the cells it ignores the custom formatting.

Comment: If you use a parameterized query, you shouldn't have to do this.

Comment: Make sure the cells are formatted as `Text`

Comment: almost: `r.Value2 = """" & r.Value2 & """"`

Comment: @Comintern can you elaborate?

Comment: `r.Value2 = chr(34) & r.Value2 & chr(34)`

Comment: Not in the space provided for comments, but [this is worth a read](https://evona.nl/simple-parameterized-queries-using-ado-in-vba/).

Comment: @Comintern infinitely more helpful than any answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to escape the single, double quote within the ... er... quotes:

```
For Each r In Range("A2", last_data)
    r.Value2 = """" & r.Value2 & """"
Next r
```

The fact that the escape character is, unfortunately, yet another double quote character, makes things a bit confusing.

So for each double quote that you want to add, you have an escape character ("), followed by the actual double quote that you want to add. These are then surrounded by two more double quotes, denoting that it is a string value.

I'm sorry if I haven't explained this well, but I hope you get the idea.

Although, as @Comintern suggests in comments, there is most likely a better way of doing what you want.